# Programmatically check Windows 10's case sensitive directory attribute

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Since April 2018, Windows 10 has had the ability to get or set if a directory was marked as case sensitive using `fsutil.exe`.

Is there a way to programmatically query the case sensitivity of a directory without running `fsutil.exe` or hackishly creating files with different casing to see if they collide?

I haven't really found any way to test this through research. I've read this is an actual NTFS attribute yet it doesn't show up when getting the file's attributes. I also noticed FindFirstFile will return the casing of the correct file if two different casings exist. Other than this I have no idea where to go as there really isn't a lot of information on this. This stuff is still pretty new.

As others have mentioned, making something case-sensitive is not a good idea in Windows due to comparability issues. I'm aware of that and my goal is to scan and work with existing case sensitive directories in the file system.

**Progress:**

I've discovered that Windows' `FindFirstFile` and friends functions respects the case sensitivity of the directory even without using the `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE`. It will not return a file with invalid casing. Now I'm trying to figure out if there's a good way to make use of this.

Comment: C++ and C# are very different languages. Please choose one. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've listed both C# and C++ as I am using C# but I can easily P/Invoke something in C++ if need be. (I have removed the C++ tag anyway)

As for attempts, I haven't really found any way to test this. I've read this is an actual NTFS attribute yet it doesn't show up when getting the file's attributes. I also noticed FindFirstFile will return the casing of the correct file if two different casings exist. Other than this I have no idea where to go as there really isn't a lot of information on this. This stuff is still pretty new.

Comment: Enabling case sensetivity in Windows -> 98% of programs broken...

Comment: @trigger_death Oh, alright, thanks for clarification. You probably could [edit] the question to include that information you posted in comment.

Comment: I'm very aware, I am not writing to set the case sensitivity but, I want to be able to scan the file system and refresh selected files accurately. When users have WSL installed, this is a real issue.

Comment: It's not exposed yet in the Windows API, at least not in the 10.0.17134 headers. You'll have to open the directory and call the native NT function, [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile): `FileCaseSensitiveInformation` in order to read the directory's [`FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_case_sensitive_information).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I've posted an answer using this method with below.

Comment: NTFS is (and always has been) case sensitive. Case-insensitivity is programmed into the Win32 subsystem.

Comment: @IInspectable, since Windows XP, case insensitivity is forced by default in the kernel object manager when calling `ObOpenObjectByName` with `ObjectType` as `NULL` (as used by `IoCreateFile`) or if the object type is flagged as case insensitive. Specifically, in those cases, if "obcaseinsensitive" is set in "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel", the object manager will forcefully add the `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to the `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: Thus `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE` (`FindFirstFileEx`) and `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` (`CreateFile`) haven't allowed case-sensitive name matching by default for about 17 years. MSDN was never updated to explain this. What happens is that those flags are implemented in the Windows API by not using the `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag (i.e. making the name implicitly case sensitive), but it's just added back by the object manager in the kernel if "obcaseinsensitive" is set.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my P/Invoke solution thanks to the help of @eryksun's comment.

**Edit 2:** Added `SetDirectoryCaseSensitive()`

**Edit 3:** Added `IsDirectoryCaseSensitivitySupported()`

I've implemented the the native method [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) while using the [`FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) `FileCaseSensitiveInformation` to read the [`FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_case_sensitive_information) structure.

```
public static partial class NativeMethods {
    public static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE = new IntPtr(-1);

    public const FileAttributes FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = (FileAttributes) 0x02000000;

    public enum NTSTATUS : uint {
        SUCCESS = 0x00000000,
        NOT_IMPLEMENTED = 0xC0000002,
        INVALID_INFO_CLASS = 0xC0000003,
        INVALID_PARAMETER = 0xC000000D,
        NOT_SUPPORTED = 0xC00000BB,
        DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY = 0xC0000101,
    }

    public enum FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS {
        None = 0,
        // Note: If you use the actual enum in here, remember to
        // start the first field at 1. There is nothing at zero.
        FileCaseSensitiveInformation = 71,
    }

    // It's called Flags in FileCaseSensitiveInformation so treat it as flags
    [Flags]
    public enum CASE_SENSITIVITY_FLAGS : uint {
        CaseInsensitiveDirectory = 0x00000000,
        CaseSensitiveDirectory = 0x00000001,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public NTSTATUS Status;
        public ulong Information;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public CASE_SENSITIVITY_FLAGS Flags;
    }

    // An override, specifically made for FileCaseSensitiveInformation, no IntPtr necessary.
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern NTSTATUS NtQueryInformationFile(
        IntPtr FileHandle,
        ref IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        ref FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION FileInformation,
        int Length,
        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
            IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct or IntPtr.Zero
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr templateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr hObject);

    public static bool IsDirectoryCaseSensitive(string directory, bool throwOnError = true) {
        // Read access is NOT required
        IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(directory, 0, FileShare.ReadWrite,
                                    IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open,
                                    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        try {
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb = new IO_STATUS_BLOCK();
            FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION caseSensitive = new FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION();
            NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, ref iosb, ref caseSensitive,
                                                        Marshal.SizeOf<FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION>(),
                                                        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileCaseSensitiveInformation);
            switch (status) {
            case NTSTATUS.SUCCESS:
                return caseSensitive.Flags.HasFlag(CASE_SENSITIVITY_FLAGS.CaseSensitiveDirectory);

            case NTSTATUS.NOT_IMPLEMENTED:
            case NTSTATUS.NOT_SUPPORTED:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_INFO_CLASS:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_PARAMETER:
                // Not supported, must be older version of windows.
                // Directory case sensitivity is impossible.
                return false;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Unknown NTSTATUS: {(uint)status:X8}!");
            }
        }
        finally {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation for setting the case sensitivity of a directory by implementing [`NTSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile). (Which has a parameter list that is identical to `NTQueryInformationFile`. Again, the problem was solved thanks to insight from @eryksun.

`FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` is a `FileAccess` flag that is not implemented in C#, so it needs to be defined and/or casted from the the value `0x100`.

```
partial class NativeMethods {
    public const FileAccess FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = (FileAccess) 0x00000100;

    // An override, specifically made for FileCaseSensitiveInformation, no IntPtr necessary.
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern NTSTATUS NtSetInformationFile(
        IntPtr FileHandle,
        ref IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        ref FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION FileInformation,
        int Length,
        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass);

    // Require's elevated priviledges
    public static void SetDirectoryCaseSensitive(string directory, bool enable) {
        // FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access is the only requirement
        IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(directory, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FileShare.ReadWrite,
                                    IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open,
                                    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        try {
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb = new IO_STATUS_BLOCK();
            FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION caseSensitive = new FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION();
            if (enable)
                caseSensitive.Flags |= CASE_SENSITIVITY_FLAGS.CaseSensitiveDirectory;
            NTSTATUS status = NtSetInformationFile(hFile, ref iosb, ref caseSensitive,
                                                    Marshal.SizeOf<FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION>(),
                                                    FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileCaseSensitiveInformation);
            switch (status) {
            case NTSTATUS.SUCCESS:
                return;
            case NTSTATUS.DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY:
                throw new IOException($"Directory \"{directory}\" contains matching " +
                                      $"case-insensitive files!");

            case NTSTATUS.NOT_IMPLEMENTED:
            case NTSTATUS.NOT_SUPPORTED:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_INFO_CLASS:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_PARAMETER:
                // Not supported, must be older version of windows.
                // Directory case sensitivity is impossible.
                throw new NotSupportedException("This version of Windows does not support directory case sensitivity!");
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Unknown NTSTATUS: {(uint)status:X8}!");
            }
        }
        finally {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I have added a method to calculate once if the version of Windows supports case sensitive directories. This just creates a folder with a constant `GUID` name in Temp and checks the `NTSTATUS` result (so it can check a folder it knows it has access to).

```
partial class NativeMethods {
    // Use the same directory so it does not need to be recreated when restarting the program
    private static readonly string TempDirectory =
        Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "88DEB13C-E516-46C3-97CA-46A8D0DDD8B2");

    private static bool? isSupported;
    public static bool IsDirectoryCaseSensitivitySupported() {
        if (isSupported.HasValue)
            return isSupported.Value;

        // Make sure the directory exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(TempDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(TempDirectory);

        IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(TempDirectory, 0, FileShare.ReadWrite,
                                IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open,
                                FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE)
            throw new Exception("Failed to open file while checking case sensitivity support!");
        try {
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb = new IO_STATUS_BLOCK();
            FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION caseSensitive = new FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION();
            // Strangely enough, this doesn't fail on files
            NTSTATUS result = NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, ref iosb, ref caseSensitive,
                                                        Marshal.SizeOf<FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION>(),
                                                        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileCaseSensitiveInformation);
            switch (result) {
            case NTSTATUS.SUCCESS:
                return (isSupported = true).Value;
            case NTSTATUS.NOT_IMPLEMENTED:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_INFO_CLASS:
            case NTSTATUS.INVALID_PARAMETER:
            case NTSTATUS.NOT_SUPPORTED:
                // Not supported, must be older version of windows.
                // Directory case sensitivity is impossible.
                return (isSupported = false).Value;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Unknown NTSTATUS {(uint)result:X8} while checking case sensitivity support!");
            }
        }
        finally {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            try {
                // CHOOSE: If you delete the folder, future calls to this will not be any faster
                // Directory.Delete(TempDirectory);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An unsupported info class is more likely to fail with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. For example, see [`FatCommonQueryInformation`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L359) and [`CdCommonQueryInfo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/cdfs/fileinfo.c#L112).

Comment: For older Windows versions, the return value should be `STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS`, which is immediately returned by the I/O manager itself if the info class is greater than or equal to `FileMaximumInformation` for the OS version. Also, I tried the redirector via "\\localhost\C$\", and it returns `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED` for an unsupported info class instead of `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Others may return `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. I'd return `false` for all of these cases since it's not an unexpected error.

Comment: Thank you again. I have added the suggested `NTSTATUS`s to the checks. I was hoping to add setter capabilities to the answer to save people the trouble of more searching, but it seems even with elevated permissions and the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` privilege on, `NTSetInformationFile` does not want to allow access to change the case sensitivity (outside of using `fsutil.exe`).

Comment: In a kernel debugger (e.g. kd.exe), you can check the required access to query/set `FileCaseSensitiveInformation`. `?? ((unsigned long *)@@(nt!IopQueryOperationAccess))[71]` is `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` (i.e. 0x80) and `?? ((unsigned long *)@@(nt!IopSetOperationAccess))[71]` is `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` (i.e. 0x100).  With 0 desired access, `CreateFile` actually uses `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`, so that explains why querying succeeds. You'll need to request `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` access to be able to set `FileCaseSensitiveInformation`.

Comment: `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` was the exact cause of the issue, turns out I don't even need elevation or `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` which is nice to know.

Comment: FYI, SeCreateGlobalPrivilege is required in order to create Section (i.e. file mapping) and SymbolicLink objects in an object directory only if it's owned by a session that's not the current session, unless the name is exempted from this check becuase it's listed in `ObpUnsecureGlobalNamesBuffer`. In particular, the global "\BaseNamedObjects" is owned by session 0 (i.e. the system services session), so you need SeCreateGlobalPrivilege to create a Section object there via `CreateFileMapping` with a global name such as "Global\SharedMemory".

Comment: Yes, you're right again. It seems the site I was referencing for information on `fsutil.exe` was telling the user to open PowerShell as an admin. Either that's no longer required or was unnecessary from the start.

Comment: Have you observed `STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY` when attempting to set `FileCaseSensitiveInformation`? I haven't seen this issue. In the Fall update we should even be able to set this flag for all subdirectories in a single system call.

Comment: I actually did encounter this, upon further inspection, it’s only returned when more than one item with the same case insensitive name exists in a directory, which isn’t very often. So I’ll need to edit the exception message.

Comment: Is this solution only suitable for local disk files or should it also work properly for samba shares (both NTFS backed and other commonly used Unix file systems that are often case-sensitive)?